# Cake PHP Form Helper

Tags: cakephp

I am facing a problem with Form Helper. My controller name is posts_controller.php and it is as below

```
<?php
    Class PostsController extends AppController
    {
        var $name='Posts';
        var $helpers=array('Html','Form','Link');
        var $components = array('Session');
        function index()
        {
            $this->pageTitle='Cake PHP Index page';            
            $this->paginate();
            $this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all'));
        }

        function view($id=null)
        {
            $this->Post->id = $id;
            $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
        }

        function add()
        {
            if(!empty ($this->data))
            {
                if($this->Post->save($this->data))
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

When I go to the add action the view add.ctp is loaded with the corresponding form.

This is my view file add.ctp

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Post');
    echo $this->input('title');
    echo $this->input('body');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

When I submit the form I am getting an error saying that posts action is not defined in your controller. And when I checked the source of the page in browser, the action of the form have a false value.The value I am getting is

```
<form id="PostAddForm" method="post" action="/cakephp/app/webroot/index.php/posts/posts/add">
```

instead of

```
<form id="PostAddForm" method="post" action="/cakephp/app/webroot/index.php/posts/add">
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable mod_rewrite on your server. For me this is the problem, especially if your code is that what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Like Nik says, it looks like a mod_rewrite problem. That form HTML should look like:

```
<form id="PostAddForm" method="post" action="/YourSite/posts/add">
```

mod_rewrite is an Apache module. Usually it is not enabled by default. There are plenty of pages explaining how to do it, but if you're on Ubuntu or Debian it can be a bit of a mystery. If that is the case, look here: http://bit.ly/ubuntu_mod_rewrite

Comment: Thanks Nik and Leo, I have got it corrected when I tried with mod_rewrite. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Also you forgot a ' in your code:

```
 echo $this->input('title);
 echo $this->input('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be written like this

```
$this->Form->create("Post",array('action'=>'add'));
```